# Ant - How to search for files in multiple folders

Tags: search, ant, jenkins

I need to write a script which searches for a file which has the file type as .jmx in a folder structure. So for example, I will have A root folder called Testing, which will contain interface names, such as customer, basket, search etc. then within each folder there will be another folder called jmxFiles, which will contain these .jmx files. 
So what I need to do is get ant to search this entire folder structure.

What I have at the minute is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project default="all">
  <!-- Define an environment variable pointing to JMETER folder or change this -->
  <property environment="env"/>
  <property name="jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format" value="xml"/>
  <property name="jmeter-home" location="${env.JMETER_DIR}"/>
  <property name="jtesting-home" location="C:/Users/MURPHYA1/Desktop/JTesting"/>
  <!-- ant-jmeter.jar comes with jmeter, be sure this is the release you have -->
  <path id="ant.jmeter.classpath">
    <pathelement
       location="${jmeter-home}/extras/ant-jmeter-1.1.1.jar" />
  </path>
  <taskdef
    name="jmeter"
    classname="org.programmerplanet.ant.taskdefs.jmeter.JMeterTask"
    classpathref="ant.jmeter.classpath" />
  <target name="clean">
    <delete dir="${jtesting-home}/results"/>
    <delete file="jmeter.log"/>
    <mkdir dir="${jtesting-home}/results/jtl"/>
    <mkdir dir="${jtesting-home}/results/html"/>
  </target>
  <target name="test" depends="clean">
    <jmeter
       jmeterhome="${jtesting-home}"
       resultlogdir="${jtesting-home}/results/jtl">
      <testplans dir="JTesting" includes="**/*.jmx"/>
      <property name="jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format" value="xml"/>
      <property name="jmeter.save.saveservice.assertion_results" value="all"/>
      <property name="jmeter.save.saveservice.bytes" value="true"/>
      <property name="file_format.testlog" value="${format}"/>
      <property name="jmeter.save.saveservice.response_data.on_error" value="${funcMode}"/>
      <property name="testData.fullPath" value="C:/TestData"/>
    </jmeter>
  </target>

  <property name="lib.dir" value="${jmeter-home}/lib"/>

    <!-- Use xalan copy from JMeter lib directory to ensure consistent processing with Java 1.4+ -->
    <path id="xslt.classpath">
        <fileset dir="${lib.dir}" includes="xalan*.jar"/>
        <fileset dir="${lib.dir}" includes="serializer*.jar"/>
    </path>

  <!-- This is not needed for the plugin, but it produces a nice html report
       which can be saved usin hudson's archive artifact feature -->
  <target name="report" depends="test">
    <xslt
       classpathref="xslt.classpath"
       basedir="results/jtl"
       destdir="results/html"
       includes="*.jtl"
       style="${jmeter-home}/extras/jmeter-results-detail-report_21.xsl"/>
  </target>
  <target name="all" depends="test, report"/>
</project>
```

will **/*.jmx work or do I need something else?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `testplans` element is, according to the JMeter docs, a standard Ant [fileset](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/fileset.html), so you can do anything described in the [Ant fileset docs](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/fileset.html). The single asterisk (`*`) is a placeholder for a single directory, whereas the double asterisk (`**`) signifies any number of subdirectories ([docs](http://ant.apache.org/manual/dirtasks.html#patterns)).

For example (I am not sure if I understand your question correctly), you could define a fileset like this:

```xml
<testplans dir="JTesting" includes="*/jmxFiles/*.jmx"/>
```

This would assume directories like this: `JTesting/basket/jmxFiles/foo.jmx`. It also assumes that your `${basedir}` is `C:/Users/MURPHYA1/Desktop`. If it is not, use an absolute path or `${jtesting-home}` for the `dir` attribute.

Comment: That was perfect mate. your code plus a minor change of an error and it worked a charm. Thank you